# ora-00936 missing expression-select statement

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, etl

I have a variable in ssis, with  query

```
SELECT     OBS_TYPE_ID, OBS_TYPE_NAME, OBS_UNIT_ID, IS_LEAF, PATH, LEVEL0_NAME, LEVEL1_NAME, LEVEL2_NAME, LEVEL3_NAME, LEVEL4_NAME, 
                      LEVEL5_NAME, LEVEL6_NAME, LEVEL7_NAME, LEVEL8_NAME, LEVEL9_NAME, LEVEL10_NAME, LEVEL0_UNIT_ID, LEVEL1_UNIT_ID, 
                      LEVEL2_UNIT_ID, LEVEL3_UNIT_ID, LEVEL4_UNIT_ID, LEVEL5_UNIT_ID, LEVEL6_UNIT_ID, LEVEL7_UNIT_ID, LEVEL8_UNIT_ID, LEVEL9_UNIT_ID, 
                      LEVEL10_UNIT_ID, HIERARCHY_LEVEL, CREATED_DATE, CREATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_DATE, LAST_UPDATED_BY
FROM         NIKUREP.NBI_DIM_OBS_V
WHERE LAST_UPDATED_DATE >= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE( @[User::LastModifiedDate] ,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

when my data flow task connects to oracle to execute this i get the ora-00396 missing expression, can someone please help, have been trying to figure this out for 1 week

Answer (score 1):

This maybe be *@[User::LastModifiedDate]* expression.

Ensure that your paramater(@[User::LastModifiedDate]) is between Single quotes.

Change your expression or try this

...

```
WHERE LAST_UPDATED_DATE >= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE( '''' || @[User::LastModifiedDate] || '''' ,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: the output of this @[User::LastModifiedDate] will be a date like '1960-01-01' so adding single quotes to parameter will make it ''1960-01-01'', also your query throwed me the same error message

Comment: what is the result of this query? can you write it somewhere or see it :  "select @[User::LastModifiedDate] from ... "                @user3132672

Comment: output will be '1960-01-01' or the max date like '2017-06-17'

Answer (score 1):

On  the variables tab click on this variable, and press `F4` to show properties Tab.

Change `Evaluate as Expression` to `True` , and Use the following expression:

```
"SELECT     OBS_TYPE_ID, OBS_TYPE_NAME, OBS_UNIT_ID, IS_LEAF, PATH, LEVEL0_NAME, LEVEL1_NAME, LEVEL2_NAME, LEVEL3_NAME, LEVEL4_NAME, 
                  LEVEL5_NAME, LEVEL6_NAME, LEVEL7_NAME, LEVEL8_NAME, LEVEL9_NAME, LEVEL10_NAME, LEVEL0_UNIT_ID, LEVEL1_UNIT_ID, 
                  LEVEL2_UNIT_ID, LEVEL3_UNIT_ID, LEVEL4_UNIT_ID, LEVEL5_UNIT_ID, LEVEL6_UNIT_ID, LEVEL7_UNIT_ID, LEVEL8_UNIT_ID, LEVEL9_UNIT_ID, 
                  LEVEL10_UNIT_ID, HIERARCHY_LEVEL, CREATED_DATE, CREATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_DATE, LAST_UPDATED_BY
FROM         NIKUREP.NBI_DIM_OBS_V
WHERE LAST_UPDATED_DATE >= TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('" + @[User::LastModifiedDate] + "','YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD')"
```

Comment: you have to add single quotations `TO_DATE('" + @[User::LastModifiedDate] + "',`

Comment: your query has resolved the problem, and i am able to preview in the data flow task, but when i execute my ssis pacakge, i get "  Description: "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error", I dont think there any paranthesis missing, any help?

Comment: Try changing the dataflow task `Delay Validation` property to `True`